# Is it relevant to keep a mBound flag when binding a service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

As explained in the documentation regarding [bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder), a `mBound` boolean is used to know whether a service was bound in an activity. Here is an excerpt of the code example given in the documentation:

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
  LocalService mService;
  boolean mBound = false;

  private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
      LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
      mService = binder.getService();
      mBound = true;
    }
}
```

Why use an additional member rather than setting `mService` to `null` if it is not bound? It seems redundant to me, and potentially [error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492149/948128).

Comment: this is just a sample implementation, you need to follow the principles, not the implementation details

Comment: @pskink I know, but this very same pattern is used in all examples I skimmed through, hence the question. So there's no catch, thanks!

Comment: in official Service docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) it is even better: see `boolean mIsBound` and when it is set to `true`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to keep an additional flag in your Activity.

Additional flag adds risk on data consistency and atomicity, such as:

- **data consistency:** Someone else modify this code may be confused on should `mBound` or `mService != null` be used, just as you're. They may worry about this and add `assert(mBound == mService != null);` check.
- **atomicity:** In strict thread safe conditions, `onServiceConnected` may just be blocked before `mBound = true;`, while in other thread, `mService` and `mBound` may conflict in state.
- **complexity:** What if someone else editing the code just modified `mBound` to other state by mistake?

Hope this could help.